# Can I create this query with Eloquent or do I need Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Can I use Eloquents active record to create this query or do I need to use the query builder?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    chat
    inner join chat_member as member1
        on member1.chat_id = chat.chat_id
    inner join chat_member as member2
        on member2.chat_id = chat.chat_id
WHERE
    member1.chat_member_id = $member1ID
    and member2.chat_member_id = $member2ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WhereHas()` function is to filter from relationship queries.

Make sure you have `Chat` and `Member` Models.
And `Chat` Model has `members()` relationship.

Then you can achieve your mysql query as follow.

```
Chat::whereHas('members', function ($query) {
    $query->where('chat_member_id', $member1ID);
})
->whereHas('members', function($query) {
    $query->where('chat_member_id', $member2ID);
})
->get();
```

*Update, I fixed a syntax issue*